# Exception when removing items from an ArrayList

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, static, removechild

I've been pondering a solution for quite some time now. Every time I attempt to remove items from an ArrayList, I always end up with an Exception error. items.add() in relation to the ArrayList works perfectly fine, though I can't get my head around as to why it throws an exception when removing items (items.remove()).

This ArrayList is for an inventory, which draws and updates each item. I used the typical for loop to iterate through each object:

for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++)

Here's the inside of my Inventory class:

```
public class Inventory {

public static boolean bOpen;
public static boolean bSelected;

private Rectangle selectBox;
private Color hover;
private Color select;
private Color color;
private Font f;
private FontMetrics fontMetrics;

public static int tileCount;
private boolean pressed;

private int sx;
private int sy;

public boolean I;
private BufferedImage HUD;
private BufferedImage infoBase;
public static ArrayList<Item> items;
private int itemCount;

// Items
public static Shovel shovel;
public static PickAxe pickAxe;
public static Key key;

public Inventory() {
    try {
        HUD = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/HUD.png"));
        infoBase = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/InfoBase.png"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    // Init items
    shovel = new Shovel();
    pickAxe = new PickAxe();
    key = new Key();

    items.add(shovel);
    items.add(pickAxe);

    hover = new Color(150, 150, 180, 180);
    select = new Color(255, 174, 0, 180);

    f = new Font("Bodoni MT", Font.PLAIN, 12);

    sx = 34;
    sy = 198;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    itemCount = items.size();

    if (I) {
        bOpen = true;
    }

    if (bOpen) {
        g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 180));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT);
        g.drawImage(HUD, 26, 194, 270, 41, null);

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                items.get(i).update();
                items.get(i).draw(g, 22 + i * 32, 180);
            }

            g.setColor(color);
            g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
            selectBox = new Rectangle(sx, sy, 32, 32);

            if (!bSelected && items.get(i) != null) {
                color = hover;
                items.get(tileCount).bSelected = false;

            } else {
                color = select;
                if (items.get(i) != null) {
                    items.get(tileCount).bSelected = true;
                    g.drawImage(infoBase, 20, 59, null);
                    g.setFont(f);
                    fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
                    int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth(items
                            .get(tileCount).getInfo());
                    g.drawString(items.get(tileCount).getInfo(),
                            GamePanel.WIDTH / 4 - width / 2, 80);
                }
            }

            g.draw(selectBox);
        }

        if (GamePanel.right) {
            bSelected = false;
            if (GamePanel.left == false) {
                if (!pressed) {
                    pressed = true;
                    if (tileCount <= itemCount - 2) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(120);
                            sx = sx + 32;
                            tileCount = tileCount + 1;
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (GamePanel.left) {
            bSelected = false;
            if (GamePanel.right == false) {
                if (!pressed) {
                    pressed = true;
                    if (tileCount > 0) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(120);
                            sx = sx + -32;
                            tileCount = tileCount - 1;
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (GamePanel.right || GamePanel.left) {
            pressed = false;
        }

        if (GamePanel.enter && itemCount > 0) {
            bSelected = true;
        }
    }

    if (itemCount > 8) {
        items.remove(8);
    }
    System.out.println(items.size());
}
```

}

Here's the class where I call the items.remove() method:

```
public class Chest extends Item {

public static boolean bOpen;

private StringEvent se;

public Chest() {
    se = new StringEvent();
    bSolid = true;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g, int x, int y) {
    setRadius(TileLayer.xx + x + getWidth() / 2, TileLayer.yy + y
            + getHeight() / 2, 32, 32);
    checkCollision();

    if (bTouched) {
        if (GamePanel.e) {
            if (Inventory.key.bSelected == true) {
                bOpen = true;
                Inventory.key.bUsed = true;
            } else
                se.draw(g, this, 2, "Chest is locked.");
        }
    }

    if (!bOpen) {
        g.drawImage(content.chestShut(), TileLayer.xx + x,
                TileLayer.yy + y, null);
    }

    if (bOpen) {
        g.drawImage(content.chestOpen(), TileLayer.xx + x,
                TileLayer.yy + y, null);
        if (Inventory.bOpen == false) {
            Audio.playOnce(Audio.unlock);
        }
    }

    if (Inventory.key.bUsed && !bRemove) {
        Inventory.items.remove(Inventory.key);
        bRemove = true;
    }
}

public void update() {
}
```

}

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem?

Edit: Here's the stacktrace:

```
Game (31) [Java Application]    
Main.Game at localhost:49264    
    Thread [AWT-Shutdown] (Running) 
    Daemon Thread [AWT-Windows] (Running)   
    Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Running) 
    Thread [Thread-2] (Suspended (exception IndexOutOfBoundsException)) 
        ArrayList<E>.rangeCheck(int) line: not available    
        ArrayList<E>.get(int) line: not available   
        Inventory.draw(Graphics2D) line: 102    
        GamePanel.draw() line: 184  
        GamePanel.run() line: 105   
        Thread.run() line: not available    
    Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)    
    Daemon Thread [Java Sound Event Dispatcher] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Direct Clip] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Direct Clip] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Direct Clip] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Direct Clip] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Direct Clip] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Direct Clip] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Direct Clip] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Direct Clip] (Running)   
    Daemon Thread [Direct Clip] (Running)   
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (18 Sep 2014 18:40:22)
```

Thanks for the help so far.

I also get this in my console:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2"
```

I tried editing the itemSize to items.size(), but unfortunately an error still occurs. I do not believe that the itemCount is the problem because the items.size() does not exceed the value of '8'.

EDIT: Ok, so I figured out the problem. items.get(i) is causing the Exception becuase of this:

```
if (!bSelected) {
                color = hover;
                if (items.get(i) != null) {
                    items.get(tileCount).bSelected = false;

            } else {
                color = select;
                if (items.get(i) != null) {
                    items.get(tileCount).bSelected = true;
                    g.drawImage(infoBase, 20, 59, null);
                    g.setFont(f);
                    fontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics();
                    int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth(items
                            .get(tileCount).getInfo());
                    g.drawString(items.get(tileCount).getInfo(),
                            GamePanel.WIDTH / 4 - width / 2, 80);
                }
            }
```

It's because as SOON as the inventory opens, it tries to set items.get(i).bSelected = true or items.get(i).bSelected = false. Maybe it's trying to find something that doesn't exist in the ArrayList anymore? Still having the same error :/

Comment: What is the exception you get?

Comment: If you want help, add the complete stacktrace to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIXED]

I had

```
if (items.get(i) != null) {
                    items.get(tileCount).bSelected = false;
                }
```

when the item that's being removed doesn't even exist! I just deleted this statement and it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Actually your code does not necessarily work how I initially thought. Please provide a stack trace as others have mentioned so it is easier to pinpoint where the issue is.

Try changing the

```
if (itemCount > 8) {
    items.remove(8);
}
```

to be

```
if (items.size() > 8) {
    items.remove(8);
}
```

You probably are removing an item in the second class which is not being reflected in the itemCount since you got that count at the top of your first draw method.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your stack: it's not the "remove" method that trigger the exception, but the "get". Looks like when you remove an object, your "tileCount" doesn't get updated properly, is it?

Comment: So if that's the case, how would I go about making sure it's being properly updated? Any Ideas?